# Get Jetpack Compose component hierarchy at runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to get the component hierarchy from the root to a specific component.

Similar to using `onNodeWithTag` to get a component and then walk up the parents to print a complete hierarchy. Can this be done at runtime within Android Compose itself (not during E2E tests)?

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Surface {
        Button(onClick = { println("Clicked: " + getComponentHierarchyHereFromRootToButton()) }
    }
}
```

So when I click the button it prints

```
Clicked MyScreen.Surface.Button
```

I found this library that will print out the entire hierarchy top-down. I'm not sure how to know which component I'm searching for (the component that triggered a callback). If that was solved, looking from that component up would be better than top down and having to search for it (but not a dealbreaker necessarily).

https://github.com/square/radiography